# Can't figure out why Sereal encoder/decoder round-trip is not returning proper object

Tags: perl, object-persistence

With all the hating on [Storable](https://metacpan.org/pod/Storable) -- I decided to check out [Sereal](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sereal%20Sereal) for serialization needs. Plus I was having some issues with 32bit/64bit cross platform issues with `Storable`, so I figured this would be a good time.

After having some issues, I boiled the problem down to the following code. (i'm persisting an `HTTP::Request` object, hence the example code).

This is my encode test, i'm storing to a file:

```
use Sereal::Encoder;
use HTTP::Request;
use HTTP::Headers;
use URI;

my $encoder = Sereal::Encoder->new();

open(my $fh, ">", 'myfile.data') or die $!;
binmode($fh);
my $uri = URI->new('http://www.example.com');
my $headers = HTTP::Headers->new(
    Content_Type => 'application/json',
);
my $http_request = HTTP::Request->new(POST => $uri, $headers, 'bleh');
print $fh $encoder->encode( $http_request );
close($fh);
```

And on the same machine(same perl etc. on 5.18), I run the following:

```
use Sereal::Decoder;
use File::Slurp qw(read_file);
use URI;

my $data = read_file('myfile.data') or die $!;
my $dec = Sereal::Decoder->new();
my $decoded = $dec->decode($data);
print $decoded->{_uri}->scheme,"\n";
```

And the output of running the encoding program, and then the decoding program is:

`Can't locate object method "scheme" via package "URI::http" at testd.pl line 8.`

Anyhow, was really nagging me as to what the problem was. I ended up reverting back to `Storable` and using `nfreeze` to solve my arch issues with `Storable` but was wondering why my attempt to transition to `Sereal` crashed and burned.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sereal, unlike Storable, won't automatically load a module when it encounters a serialized object. This is a security issue with Storable, so Sereal is working as intended.[[1]](http://www.masteringperl.org/2012/12/the-storable-security-problem/)

At the point where `scheme` is called in the second test program, URI::http hasn't been loaded yet, so the method call results in an error. It seems that URI *will* load its subclasses when its constructor is used on a string that "looks like" one of them, e.g.

```
URI->new('http://www.stackoverflow.com');
```

loads the URI::http module. So one solution would be to add a dummy invocation of that constructor to ensure URI::http is loaded, or manually `use URI::http` instead. Either option causes the `print $decoded->{_uri}->scheme` line of the second script to work as expected, but I think the second is the lesser of two evils (importing an undocumented submodule from URI versus an arbitrary method call done specifically for its not-immediately-obvious side effect).

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, I didn't realize the issue with the sub-classes and agree on the selection of the lesser of two evils. Thanks again.